# Возникает ошибка?

Tags: php, веб-программирование, mvc

Выдает такую ошибку:

```
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: 8192

Message: Methods with the same name as their class will not be constructors in a future version of PHP; DX_Auth has a deprecated constructor

Filename: libraries/DX_Auth.php

Line Number: 16
```

Перевод ошибки: методы с тем же именем, что и их класс, не будут конструкторами в будущей версии.

Использую библиотеку **фреймворк Codelgniter**.
Признателен за ответ и помощь.

Comment: конструктор `DX_Auth` нужно заменить на `__constructor`. Ну и везде где такое встречается. Если это в фреймворке, тогда обновить фреймворк до актуальной версии

Comment: Благодарен за помощь !